# Convergence of a countable sum of characteristic functions of half-open intervals with coefficients

Tags: characteristic-functions, pointwise-convergence

Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and denote by $\chi_A$ the characteristic function of $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $I_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded nonempty half-open interval of type $[a,b)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_n|\mu(I_n)$ converges.

Is it true that the function $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\chi_{I_n}$ converges pointwise almost everywhere? If so, how to prove it?

Two observations:

- if $\mu(I_n)$ were bounded below by a positive constant, say $m$, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_n|\mu(I_n)\geq m\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_n|$ so that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_n|$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\chi_{I_n}$ would converge (the last everywhere)
- $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\chi_{I_n}$ may fail to converge at a point. Example: $a_n=1$ and $I_n=[0,(n+1)^{-2})$ so that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|\mu(I_n)<\infty$ but $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\chi_{I_n}(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1$ diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Tonelli's Theorem $\int \sum |a_n| \chi_{I_n} d\mu = \sum |a_n| \int \chi_{I_n} d\mu=\ \sum |a_n|\mu(I_n) <\infty$. This implies that $\sum |a_n|\chi_{I_n} <\infty$ almost everywhere so the series converges absolutely at almost all points.

PS Tonelli's Theorem can be replaced by Monotone Convergence Theorem or Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: I think you implicitly used the fact that an integrable function is finite a.e. no ?

Comment: Yes, if $f \geq 0$ and $\int f d\mu <\infty$ then $f<\infty$ a.e.

Comment: Of course sigma finiteness is satisfied. We can also use Monotne Convergence Theorem since the partial sums form an increasing sequence. @Surb

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: What is the measure for the sum ?

Comment: Infinite sums can be considered as integrals with respect to counting measure on the integers. So we are applying Tonelli's Theorem to $\mu \times \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Sorry, I see now. Thank you. I was thinking about the counting measure over $\mathbb R$ (which is not $\sigma -$finite). But over $\mathbb N$ it's of course $\sigma -$finite. Good point (+1)